# Multiple possible inputs

Tags: python, input

I'm just getting stared on python, and I thought it would be fun to make a small quiz. The problem I have is that there are lots of possible answers when you take into account capitol letters & common misspellings. I want to account for these, but not have stacks of 'elif' functions. Is there a way to get all of the possible answers onto one line? Something similar to || in C.
Code example:

```
y = input("Where was the 2004 Olympics held? ")
if y == "Athens":
    print ("Correct!")
    score = score + 1
```

But allowing `'athens'` or `'Greece'` as answers

Answer (score 4):

what you want is:

```
answer = input("Where was the 2004 Olympics held? ")
if answer.lower() in ("athens", "greece"):
    print ("Correct!")
    score = score+1
```

I'm also lowering the answer, so the case does not matter!

N.B.: to build a quiz, here's how I'd do it:

```
qas = {
    'Where was the 2004 Olympics held?': ['athens', 'greece'],
    'What is the answer of the question about life, the universe and everything?': ['42', 'forty-two'] 
    …
}

for q, a in qas:
    ans = input(q)
    if ans.lower() in a:
        print("Correct!")
        score += 1
```

Comment: Thanks. It's all indented, but the copy paste seemed to mess it up.

Answer (score 3):

```
if y.lower() in ["athens", "greece"]:
    print("Correct!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup!

Just do:

```
if y in ["athens", "blah", "other",...]:
    print ("Correct!")
    score += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y = input("Where was the 2004 Olympics held? ")
if y in ["Athens","Greece"]:
    print ("Correct!")
    score = score+1
```